# Nginx Ingress Controller on Bare Metal expose problem

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

i try to deploy `nginx-ingress-controller` on bare metal , I have

**4 Node**

1. 10.0.76.201 - Node 1
2. 10.0.76.202 - Node 2
3. 10.0.76.203 - Node 3
4. 10.0.76.204 - Node 4

**4 Worker**

5. 10.0.76.205 - Worker 1
6. 10.0.76.206 - Worker 2
7. 10.0.76.207 - Worker 3
8. 10.0.76.214 - Worker 4

**2 LB**

9. 10.0.76.208 - LB 1
10. 10.0.76.209 - Virtual IP (keepalave)
11. 10.0.76.210 - LB 10

Everything is on `BareMetal` , Load balancer located outside Cluster .

**This is simple haproxy config , just check 80 port ( Worker ip )**

```
frontend kubernetes-frontends
  bind *:80
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  default_backend kube



backend kube
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        cookie lsn insert indirect nocache
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor
        server node-1 10.0.76.205:80 maxconn 1000 check
        server node-2 10.0.76.206:80 maxconn 1000 check
        server node-3 10.0.76.207:80 maxconn 1000 check
        server node-4 10.0.76.214:80 maxconn 1000 check
```

I Install nginx-ingress-controller using Helm and everything work fine

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-xb5rw        0/1     Completed   0          18m
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-skt7t         0/1     Completed   2          18m
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86-htrhs   1/1     Running     0          18m

NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.106.233.186   <none>        80:30659/TCP,443:32160/TCP   18m
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.102.132.131   <none>        443/TCP                      18m

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           18m

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-6dc865cd86   1         1         1       18m

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           24s        18m
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           34s        18m
```

**Deploy nginx simple way and works fine**

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx:1.18
kubectl scale deploy/nginx --replicas=6
kubectl expose deploy/nginx --type=NodePort --port=80
```

after , i decided to create `ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tektutor-ingress 
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "tektutor.training.org"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/nginx"
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx 
            port:
              number: 80
```

works fine

```
kubectl describe ingress tektutor-ingress

Name:             tektutor-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.0.76.214
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                   Path  Backends
  ----                   ----  --------
  tektutor.training.org
                         /nginx   nginx:80 (192.168.133.241:80,192.168.226.104:80,192.168.226.105:80 + 3 more...)
Annotations:             kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                         nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  18m                nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for default/tektutor-ingress was added or updated
  Normal  Sync            18m (x2 over 18m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

everything work fine , when i try curl any ip works `curl (192.168.133.241:80,192.168.226.104:80,192.168.226.105:80 + 3 more...)`

now i try to add hosts

```
10.0.76.201 tektutor.training.org
```

This is my master ip , is it correct to add here master ip ? when i try  `curl tektutor.training.org` not working

Can you please explain what I am having problem with this last step?
I set the IP wrong? or what ? Thanks !

I hope I have written everything exhaustively

I used to this tutor [Medium Install nginx Ingress Controller](https://medium.com/tektutor/using-nginx-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes-bare-metal-setup-890eb4e7772)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Put in your haproxy backend config values shown below instead of the ones you've provided:

- `30659` instead of `80`
- `32160` instead of `443` (if needed)

---

More explanation:

`NodePort` works on certain set of ports (default: `30000`-`32767`) and in this scenario it allocated:

- `30659` for your ingress-nginx-controller port `80`.
- `32160` for your ingress-nginx-controller port `443`.

This means that every request trying to hit your cluster from **outside** will need to contact this ports (30...).

You can read more about it by following official documentation:

- [Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: Thanks For answering , when i try open with http://10.0.76.201:30659/ 
" 404 Not Found " Nginx

Comment: This is node ip , if it's work after i add into haproxy , but not open... I can't figure out what's wrong, as if I have everything right.

Comment: It will show you not found as your Ingress definition works for domain name and not the IP. Ingress controller reads Host header

Comment: Thanks . But same problem see my haproxy config, I couldn't do it for 2 days. :/ 
https://im.ge/i/O6Eewq

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: Have i question , my sergice "nginx just pods" running with nodeport 80:31422/TCP or it's must be with clusterip?

Answer (score 0):

A funny story that took 2 days :) In Ingress i have used the path /nginx but not hitting it while

Something like :
http://tektutor.training.org/nginx

THanks @Dawid Kruk who try to helm me :) !